# STM32 F302R8 Nucleo I2C Notworking

Tags: c, stm32, i2c, atmega, nucleo

I have got a problem with the development of a i2c communication between a ATMega328 and a STM32 F302R8 controller.

Below the initialisation code of the st controller, generated by Cube.

```
void MX_I2C2_Init(void) {

hi2c2.Instance = I2C2;
hi2c2.Init.Timing = 0x2000090E;
hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
hi2c2.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
hi2c2.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
hi2c2.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
hi2c2.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c2) != HAL_OK) {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

/**Configure Analogue filter
 */
if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c2, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE)
        != HAL_OK) {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

/**Configure Digital filter
 */
if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c2, 0) != HAL_OK) {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}
HAL_I2C_MspInit(&hi2c2);
}

void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef* i2cHandle) {

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
if (i2cHandle->Instance == I2C2) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C2_MspInit 0 */

    /* USER CODE END I2C2_MspInit 0 */

    /**I2C2 GPIO Configuration
     PA9     ------> I2C2_SCL
     PA10     ------> I2C2_SDA
     */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9 | GPIO_PIN_10;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* I2C2 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_I2C2_CLK_ENABLE()
    ;
    /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C2_MspInit 1 */

    /* USER CODE END I2C2_MspInit 1 */
}
```

}

I added the `HAL_I2C_MspInit(&hi2c2);` call for setting the pins in the right mode.

The Function SerialMain part of a thread and will be called regularly.

```
void SerialMain(void const* arg) {
MX_USART1_UART_Init();
MX_I2C2_Init();
char *buffer = "Hello World! ";
int cnt = 0;
for (;;) {
    cnt++;
    if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c2, 8 , buffer, 13, 1000) != HAL_OK) { //PA9   SCL PA10 SDA
        SerialError();
    }
    if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c2, 8 >> 1, &cnt, sizeof(cnt), 1000)
            != HAL_OK) { //PA9 SCL PA10 SDA
        SerialError();
    }
    osDelay(10);

}

}
```

After trying to transmit the  Hello World message the HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit will return HAL_TIMEOUT.

Does someone know why it returns HAL_TIMEOUT?

Does someone know how to transmit data successfully?

Comment: What code do you have running on the Mega328? Without a device configured at that address, you will get timeouts when you try to select it.

Comment: It is [link]https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterReader Code for Slave Sender - Program for Arduino 2 running at the Mega328. The address is set with  Wire.begin(8);

Comment: The solution was very  easy. It was an not cleared interrupt.